# В аккаунт Microsoft приходят коды подтвержения для действий, которые я не совершал, при этом история активности пуста

Tags: windows

Знаю, что ресурс не совсем профильный, задал этот вопрос на answers.microsoft.com, но там ответа нет.

Мне периодически приходят SMS от Microsoft "Используйте *** как код безопасности". История активности показывает только мой компьютер. После нескольких смен пароля я отключил подтверждение входа по SMS и оставил только по email. Тогда мне пришло SMS "Используйте *** как код сброса пароля". Пароль не изменился, а история активности по-прежнему показывает только мой компьютер. С него запрос выполниться не мог — когда пришло SMS, он был выключен. Это что-то очень странное и непонятное, я уже подумываю о том, чтобы переустановить Windows (хотя антивирусы никаких вирусов не находят). Для хранения паролей я использую менеджер паролей Bitwarden. О случаях, когда он крал пароли, не известно.

Что пробовал / попробую позже:

1. <s>Менять пароль из-под своей Windows</s>
2. <s>Отвязать номер телефона от получения кодов доступа</s>
3. Поменять пароль из-под Linux, не заходить в Windows
4. Переустановить Windows
5. Привязать к учётной записи другой номер телефона
6. Не использовать Bitwarden для генерации и хранения пароля

Comment: Пока по описанию больше похоже что кто-то пытается взломать (а не взломал) ваш аккаунт.

Comment: Если только попытки, то откуда до отвязки номера от 2FA были сообщения "Используйте *** как код безопасности"? Они приходят уже после ввода пароля, что по идее должно быть отражено в истории активности.

Comment: ¿Как определили, что SMS от Microsoft?

Comment: Приходили с того же номера, на который мне шли коды для входа, когда я сам входил.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае будет более правильно обратиться в техподдержку Microsoft.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/624678)

Comment: @DarthKYL -  не согласен с вами и вот почему - у спрашивающего явные проблемы и инфраструктурой Microsoft и подозрения на взлом учетки. Кто кроме техподдержки самой Microsoft имеет средства для решения данной проблемы?

Answer (score 2):

Удалось полностью убрать возможность использовать SMS для восстановления пароля, установив на мобильник [Microsoft Authenticator](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/account/authenticator). Пункт с кодом по SMS исчез из меню восстановления утраченного пароля, что убирает теоретическую возможность взлома перехватом SMS. Ну и винду на всякий случай тоже переустановлю)

Если это действительно были попытки подобрать пароль, а не какой-то сбой на стороне Microsoft, то поток SMS должен прекратиться.

Comment: Upd.: Странно, но недавно подобное SMS снова пришло... Ну хоть теперь не так часто.